# Filter current directory in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Is there any way to filter current directory with some string and display only matching files/directories? I don't want to include subdirectories (this has to be quick, just like filtering in Google Drive). I'd be perfect if it was results-as-you-type.

(edit)
Example:

I see files/directories:

```
AAABBB
AAABBBCCC
AAABBBCCCDDD
LALA
```

I type: "AAA" and immediately see:

```
AAABBB
AAABBBCCC
AAABBBCCCDDD
```

type: "AAABBBCCC" and immediately see:

```
AAABBB
AAABBBCCC
AAABBBCCCDDD
```

Note: I DON'T CARE about what's inside these dirs.

Comment: I believe you do it by typing in the search box in the upper right hand corned of Explorer. If you are filtering in a non-indexed location, you might have to click Advanced Search and tune the search to use include non-indexed files. I've never used Google Drive, so I don't know how they compare.

Comment: this includes subdirectories too, and I'd like to filter directories/files in current directory only

Comment: In Windows 8 - the "Search Tools" ribbon in windows explorer includes a "current folder" option (and an "all subfolders").  I'm pretty sure it was there in Windows 7 too (but I'd have to fire up a VM to confirm).

Answer (score 0):

List directories and files at current directory match string "re":

```
dir /A:- *re*
```

List files at current directory match "r":

```
dir /A:-D- *r*
```

List directories at current directory match "r":

```
dir /A:D- *r*
```

If need subsirectories use `/S`

Comment: The reason I'm asking about how to do this in Windows Explorer is because I want to do this without switching to cmd/cygwin ;-)